# C# DLL cannot affect value of a number passed by reference from a VB6 application

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a legacy VB6 application that calls a VB6 DLL, and I am trying to port the VB6 DLL to C# without yet touching the main VB6 application code.  The old VB6 DLL had one interface that received a VB6 long (32-bit integer) by reference, and updated the value.  In the C# DLL I have written, the updated value is never seen by the main VB6 application.  It acts as though what was really marshalled to the C# DLL was a reference to a copy of the original data, not a reference to the original data.  I can successfully pass arrays by reference, and update them, but single values aren't behaving.

The C# DLL code looks something like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IInteropDLL
{
   void Increment(ref Int32 num);
}
[ComVisible(true)]
public class InteropDLL : IInteropDLL
{
    public void Increment(ref Int32 num) { num++; }
}
```

The calling VB6 code looks something like this:

```
Private dll As IInteropDLL
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set dll = New InteropDLL
End Sub
Private Sub TestLongReference()
    Dim num As Long
    num = 1
    dll.Increment( num )
    Debug.Print num      ' prints 1, not 2.  Why?
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?  What would I have to do to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As C# allows you direct control over the classIDs, you can completeley emulate the odl COM interface so no changes required in the client either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB6 pass by value and pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262186/vb6-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 10):

```
dll.Increment( num )
```

Because you are using parentheses, the value is forcibly passed by value, not by reference (the compiler creates a temporary copy and passes *that* by reference).

Remove the parentheses:

```
dll.Increment num
```

---

EDIT: [A more complete explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683) by [MarkJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15639/markj).

Comment: Nice call.  Definitely one of the more bizarro features of VB6.  It makes sense that it works that way but it takes some imagination.  Argument passing was ByRef by default.

Comment: That was it!  Wow!  I never knew about that behavior of VB6.  Now that I know this, I can think of other times I was bitten, but just found other workarounds.  Thanks!!

Comment: Oh, and please copy and paste code sample, not rewrite/obfuscate as it can hide oddities/bugs like that.

Comment: The paranthesis behavior in this case changes in you had useed Call instead.  I *always* use the Call MyMethed(Param) convention to avoid that evaluation behavior.  Plus The C and Java in my past makes me uneasy if I don't see paranthesis when invoking functions :)

Comment: If you see a space between your method call and the first bracket `MethodCall ("foo")`- this is your queue to investigate an issue - either remove the brackets or add `Call`. After some time, spotting this becomes second nature!