# Excel 2011 VBA - custom function to get the last row in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying out various ways of finding the last row in a range and returning this number to a subroutine, to no avail.

Here's the code I have

```
Sub StartHere()
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Set oSheet = WorkSheets(1)
    ProcessData(oSheet)
End Sub

Sub ProcessData(ByVal wkst As Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'set range
    Set rng = wkst.Range("L:S") 'Range that i want to process data on

    'get the last row (in Long datatype)
    lastRow = CLng(getLastRowInRange(rng))

End Sub

Function getLastRowInRange(ByRef rng As Range)
    getLastRowInRange = rng.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows,_ SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Function
```

I keep getting Type Mismatch on the

```
getLastRowInRange = rng.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows,_ SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Any clues, guys?

Comment: Hi GSerg, no it isn't a duplicate. I had no problems when I tried the getLastRowInRange function by itself, but had problems when i integrated it with StartHere() and ProcessData() subroutines. So I want to figure out what's the problem with my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ProcessData(oSheet)
```

[Remove the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070033/c-sharp-dll-cannot-affect-value-of-a-number-passed-by-reference-from-a-vb6-appli/8070104#8070104).

Otherwise you are passing the value of the default property of the `oSheet` object, which it doesn't have. You should be getting "Object doesn't support this property or method" though.

After doing that, change the function call:

```
getLastRowInRange = rng.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

`After` must belong to the search range. `A1` doesn't belong to `L:S`.

Finally, make sure you handle the case when `Find` returns `Nothing` (which you don't at the moment, happily calling `.Row` on the returned object).

Comment: Hi GSerg, Thanks it works! btw, what does rng.Cells(1) refer to? Also I tried to remove the parentheses but excel 2011 stopped it - error. I put it back on and it works.

Comment: @Yakult121 Are you using Excel for Mac? It may have its differences in regard of syntax. `rng.cells(1)` is the first cell of `rng`.