# Dim statement without type in classic vbscript / classic asp

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript, asp-classic, initialization, variable-types

In legacy code, I have found a "Dim" statement without type in classic vbscript  / classic asp

```
Dim x1
```

Is there a default type (such as object) that x1 acquires?

Is it true that vb might 'work backwords' and if later it encounters
x1 =3 
or 
x1 = 'Name'

it will assign the relevant type (integer and string) respectively?

NOTE:  The code involved really does work in the real world.  Therefore, this isn't a bug, just an unfortunate (IMHO) 'feature' of classic VB ...

Thanks

Comment: Variant, very funny things happened with them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218803/vb6-variant-type

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are no data types in classic asp, every variable is of a variant type. in fact, you explicitly cannot declare a data type when DIMing a variable, it's incorrect syntax.

However, once a variable contains data, you can then force the data type you want to use by using specific functions such as:

CInt( x )     convert to a integer

CDbl( x )     convert to a decimal

CStr( x )     convert to a string

CBool( x )    convert to a boolean

you can see how this is useful:

```
Response.Write ( CInt( "4" ) = 4 )       true
Response.Write ( CInt( "4" ) = "4" )     false
```