# VB6 - calling subs

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am modifying a legacy project that must run in VB6, and I have OOP experience but not VB.

Anyway I thought this would be straightforward, I need to add data to a hashmap.

I can call the retreive data function but not the set data function.

Here is the set data function (or sub I guess).

```
Sub SetSetting(Name As String, Value)
    Member of MBCSettings.MBCSettings
    Store the named setting in the current settings map
```

So if I try to set something like this:

```
  gobjMBCSettings.SetSetting("UserName", "223")
```

I get:  Compiler Error, Expected "="

Is my object broken or am I missing something obvious?  Thanks.

Comment: Try without the parens: `gobjMBCSettings.SetSetting "UserName", "223"`

Comment: That works, thanks!  Such an odd language.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107259/is-it-possible-to-call-a-vb-function-without-the-parenthesis and a number of other questions all related to this

Comment: Not so odd really, method calls with no return value were intended to look like new language verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah VB6... yes.

In order to invoke a method the standard way you do not use parentheses:

```
gobjMBCSettings.SetSetting "UserName", "223"
```

If you want to use parentheses, tack in the `call` command:

```
Call gobjMBCSettings.SetSetting("UserName", "223")
```

It should be noted that using parentheses around `ByRef` argument without the `Call` keyword, the argument will be sent in as `ByVal`.

```
Public Sub MySub(ByRef foo As String)
    foo = "some text"
End Sub

Dim bar As String
bar = "myText"
MySub(bar)
' bar is "myText"
Call MySub(bar)
' bar is "some text"
```

It only complained because you were passing in multiple parameters wrapped with a single set of parentheses. Using `()` to force `ByVal` also works in VB.NET.

Comment: `using parentheses around ByRef argument without the Call keyword, the argument will be sent in as ByVal.` ... That is absolutely disgusting.

Comment: @helrich: It's an expression. If you use `val + 0` instead of `(val)` the expression will be calculated in a temp local var which in turn will be passed `ByRef`.