# VBA does not accept my method calling and gives Compile error: Syntax error

Tags: debugging, excel, vba

```
Public Sub SavePendleValues(ByVal row1 As Integer, ByVal row2 As Integer)
```

Calling it

```
For sheetrow = 2 To 15 ' number of rows to scan
    SavePendleValues (sheetrow, sheetrow)
Next sheetrow
```

Getting error : `Compile error: Syntax error`

When I uncomment the line: `SavePendleValues (sheetrow, sheetrow)`

Everything works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Remove the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257503/11683).

```
SavePendleValues sheetrow, sheetrow
```

Otherwise you are trying to pass as a first argument something in parentheses that has two variables in it, which doesn't make sense for VBA parser.

Comment: Simply brilliant, brilliantly simple. +1

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this compile error syntax error, I copied code from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb206765(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
So the code should be good.

Then, somehow, I removed all the leading empty spaces for all lines, the error goes away!
So it seems, the vba editor is not very tolerant, it doesn't like certain invisible printing-control characters.