# VB 6 Call requirement and restriction

Tags: vb6

I have several class member functions that look very similar:

```
Public Function ProcessSomething(ByVal X as Currency, ByVal Y as Long) As Boolean
```

Yet some of these function the IDE is forcing me to use the call statement on and other not.

Can someone give me some understanding here?

Comment: the ones it wants you to use CALL with are not functions, but are subs as in `Public Sub DoSomething`

Comment: Probably worth checking: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15040060/11683

Comment: all of them are function. some require the call statement others do now.

Comment: see explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/15639)

Answer (score 6):

The `Call` statement is required if you are calling the `Function` and ignoring the return value, or if you use the `(..)` brackets.

Example, in the following invokation, we are invoking `ProcessSomething` but not taking the return `Boolean` (essentially ignoring it.)

```
Call ProcessSomething(currencyObj, 1.2345)
```

If you want to invoke the function and ignore the return value, and still not use `Call`, then you would invoke it as follows. (notice `(...)` are missing ).

```
ProcessSomething currencyObj, 1.2345
```