# Inserting picture into Excel sheet with VBA fails

Tags: excel, insert, vba

I want to embed a picture into a file and found this on stackoverflow but cannot get it to work.  There is probably something simple that I cannot find - get syntax error.

```vba
Insert(Filename:= C:\Users\chill\Desktop\picture.jpg, LinkToFile:= False, SaveWithDocument:= True)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA does not accept my method calling and gives Compile error: Syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040060/vba-does-not-accept-my-method-calling-and-gives-compile-error-syntax-error)

Comment: you need double quotes around your filename and path

Comment: That is what I had tried earlier and now and no luck.....

Comment: did not send this......Insert(Filename:= "C:\Users\chill\Desktop\FireCorps.Black-White.Logo.jpg", LinkToFile:= False, SaveWithDocument:= True)

Comment: then you need to expand your included code (edit the question) as `xlApp.activesheet.Pictures.Insert(...)` should insert a *linked* picture. If you want to embed it - [you'll have to do something different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110425/vba-to-insert-embeded-picture-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Try something a bit simpler

```
  ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ("C:\Users\davesexcel\Pictures\Picture 2.jpg")
```