# Title of Message box not setting up

Tags: visual-studio-6

I am writing some code in Visual Basic 6. It also uses the `Msgbox` funtion. Now I searched this and I got to know that if you want to set the title of the Message box then this is the syntax:

```
Msgbox(<Prompt>,<Title>)
```

For example, I write this:

```
MsgBox ("Incorrect Answer!","QM")
```

It says:

Compile Error
Expected: =

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Visual Studio is not used to code in Visual Basic 6, add the correct tag and remove the meaningless ones thanks

Comment: For your info., there was a "Visual Studio 6.0" too.

Comment: Anyways, I am doing it

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA does not accept my method calling and gives Compile error: Syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040060/vba-does-not-accept-my-method-calling-and-gives-compile-error-syntax-error)

Comment: @GSerg, can you tell me how is it a duplicate of that?

Comment: Because you need to remove the parentheses @Siddhant, otherwise [you are trying to pass as a first argument something in parentheses that has two variables in it, which doesn't make sense for the parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040102/11683).

Answer (score 1):

With VB6, you can either request a response, and do something based on the answer, or you can simply display a message.

If you want to know what button was clicked, you need to use the function format - that is, you must use the brackets.

If you simply want to display a message, then you don't use the brackets.

So if  you want to just display the message, then continue, do this:

```
MsgBox "Incorrect Answer!", , "QM"
```

But if you want to know which button the user clicked (e.g. to offer them a try again, cancel, then you need a variable, and you use the brackets to signifify that it's a function:

```
Dim response = MsgBox("Try again?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "QM")
```

You can then look at the `response` variable to find out which button the user clicked.

A couple of pages for reference:

http://vb6reference.tomswebdesign.net/msgbox.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx