# Calling Subs from an Add-In

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with some basic opening code in `Workbook_Open` and some code in `xSheet` i.e.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Run s00Config_Worksheet_SelectionChange(Target)

End Sub
```

where sub `s00Config_Worksheet_SelectionChange` exists in an Excel AddIn which is loaded (and visible for the moment).

But when I execute the program in the first sheet all I get is Sub or Function not defined.

In the AddIn the sub has been defined as

```
Public Sub s00Config_Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

Questions are:

1. Am I thinking this the right way, and
2. How do I get my excel sheet to execute subs in the Excel AddIn (XLAm), there are a lot of them

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you reference the addin in your VBA project (Tools - References - Browse).
2. Remove `Run` and the [parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257503/11683):

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
       s00Config_Worksheet_SelectionChange Target
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`Run` is provided by Excel, and VBA sees it as just a normal subroutine. So when you say `Run s00Config_Worksheet_SelectionChange(Target)`, VBA tries to evaluate the function *immediately*  and then pass it to `Run` as its first argument. To prevent VBA from interfering like this, `Run` requires that you pass it the target subroutine name as a string, and then proceed with the rest of the target's argument list:

```
Run "s00Config_Worksheet_SelectionChange", Target
```

The same syntax applies if you want to get a value back from whatever function you call:

```
v = Run("s00Config_Worksheet_SelectionChange", Target)
```