# Passing array as argument to a Class setter using VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I need to pass a `String` array to set a class property using its setter method. Array was declared in Module and it's perfectly set the values using `Redim Preserve`. When calling the Class setter method it gives error. If I continued to without setting array data type it worked. But I need to declare the data type as `String`.

I received a compile error "Type mismatch: array or user defined type expected."

```
Module

    Dim sPageDetails() As String
    ' set some values to array

    ' Declare class instance
    dim x as new X
    with x
       .SetPageNumberDetails(sPageDetails)  ' assume SetPageNumberDetails is the setter method in class X
    end with
End module
```

```
'class module start X
Private pageDetails() as String

' Setter for pageDetails array
Public Sub SetPageNumberDetails(ByRef sPageDetails() As String)
    pageDetails= sPageDetails
End Sub

' Getter for pageDetails array
Public Function GetPageNumberDetails() As String()
    GetPageNumberDetails= pageDetails
End Function
```

Comment: Sure looks like an obvious candidate to be a property instead of a pair of methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> .SetPageNumberDetails(sPageDetails)
> ```

[Remove the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8070104/11683):

```
.SetPageNumberDetails sPageDetails
```

Answer (score -1):

**Remain the parentheses** and add explicit 'Call':

```
Call .SetPageNumberDetails(sPageDetails)
```

It took 5-10 CPU ticks (~30 nsec), but code wil be more readable, editable,  auditable etc. And it is simply *comme il faut...*
.