# Unable to refresh VBA code programatically

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a routine that looks like this:

```
Private Sub RefreshByName(strFileType As String)
Dim strFile As String

strFile = Dir(".\*." & strFileType, vbNormal)

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Dim strCompName As String
    Dim vbComp As Object
    strCompName = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
    'Fails here
    vbComp = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(strCompName)
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.import (strFile)
    strFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

According to most of what I read online, it should be possible to reference the VBComponents by name, but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Generally the error I get is `Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method`. - that isn't the error I get on this specific variant of the code - rather this is an `error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set`.

But I broke up all the declarations to see the exact part of the line that caused the problem. In playing with this to get the exact error message, It suddenly worked on me (inexplicably, to me anyway) I'm trying to find the correct combination now, but any help with the error messages would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of the generic "it doesn't work," please be specific.

Comment: When you `debug.print`, what is the value of `strCompName`?

Comment: @Marc, it is Accounts in this case. It is the correct name.

Comment: @DougGlancy, I expanded my question.

Comment: `vbComp =` should be `Set vbComp =`, and I'm way not sure names of VBE components always match their file names.

Comment: @GSerg, thanks, they may generally not. But I'm just doing a little script, and in this case they do. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [not using `Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17877644/11683) when you should:

```
Set vbComp = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(strCompName)
```

You might also want to [remove the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538232/11683) from `.import (strFile)`.