# Type mismatch using byref

Tags: vba, excel, byref, listobject

The following code creates a compile time error message "type mismatch":

```
Private Sub Example  
    JustAdd(Sheet1.ListObjects("Table6"))
End Sub

Public Sub JustAdd(ByRef tableN As ListObject)  
   tableN.ListRows.Add
End Sub
```

Also tried:

```
Private Sub Example  
    Dim tmp As ListObject
    Set tmp = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table6")
    JustAdd(tmp)
End Sub

Public Sub JustAdd(ByRef tableN As ListObject)  
   tableN.ListRows.Add
End Sub
```

Also:

```
Private Sub Example  
    Dim tmp As ListObject
    tmp = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table6")
    JustAdd(tmp)
End Sub

Public Sub JustAdd(ByRef tableN As ListObject)  
   tableN.ListRows.Add
End Sub
```

Just need a quick nudge in the right direction to get this JustAdd subroutine working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing array as argument to a Class setter using VB 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538094/passing-array-as-argument-to-a-class-setter-using-vb-6-0)

Comment: Worth a read: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I only tried your first example but I believe any of them should work with this slight modification.

```
Call JustAdd(Sheet1.ListObjects("Table6"))
```

**EDIT¹:** OK, maybe not the third one.

**EDIT²:** More information at: [Calling Sub and Function Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251432(v=office.15).aspx) (Applies to: Office 2013 | VBA)

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to tell OP to drop the parenthesis rather than use an obsolete keyword from an ancient version of Excel Macros? (It's not even VBA.....) Perhaps some explanation about what is going on and *why* doing this works?

Comment: @RubberDuck - Good advice. I've added a link to some current MSDN documentation on the subject.