# Why is 31 >= 20 returning False here when comparing day?

Tags: vba, excel

I was debugging this code but I am not sure why this is returning false instead of true.

```
?Day(i)>salday(0)
False
?Day(i)
 31 
?salday(0)
20
?isnumeric(day(i))
True
?isnumeric(salday(0))
True
```

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub genOP()

Dim wO As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim stDate, enDate, intVal, entR As Long, salDay, salAmt, stTime, enTime, dbMin, dbMax
Dim stRow As Long
Dim cet, curMn


'On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

stDate = STG.Range("B2"): enDate = STG.Range("B4")
intVal = Split(STG.Range("B3"), ","): entR = STG.Range("B5")
salDay = Split(STG.Range("B6"), "-")
salAmt = STG.Range("B7"): stTime = STG.Range("B8"): enTime = STG.Range("B9"): dbMin = STG.Range("B10"): dbMax = STG.Range("B11")

Set wO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
TEMP.Cells.Copy wO.Range("A1")

stRow = 19
curMn = Month(stDate)

For i = CLng(stDate) To CLng(enDate)

    If stRow > 19 Then
        wO.Rows(stRow & ":" & stRow).Copy
        wO.Rows(stRow + 1 & ":" & stRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    cet = Trim(DESC.Range("A" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(2, DESC.UsedRange.Rows.Count)))

    If STG.Range("B14") = "ON" Then
       cet = cet & "Transaction amount " & Chr(34) & "&TEXT(H" & stRow & "," & Chr(34) & "#,##0.00" & Chr(34) & ")&" & Chr(34) & " GEL,"
    End If
    If STG.Range("B13") = "ON" Then
       cet = cet & Chr(34) & "&TEXT(B" & stRow & "-1," & Chr(34) & "dd mmm yyyy" & Chr(34) & ")&" & Chr(34)
    End If
    If STG.Range("B12") = "ON" Then
       cet = cet & " " & Format(stTime + Rnd * (enTime - stTime), "HH:MM AM/PM")
    End If

    If curMn = Month(i) And (Day(i) >= salDay(0) And Day(i) <= salDay(1)) Then  'Salary Day
        cet = Trim(DESC.Range("A" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(2, DESC.UsedRange.Rows.Count)))
        wO.Range("B" & stRow) = Format(i, "DD-MM-YYYY")
        wO.Range("I" & stRow) = salAmt
        wO.Range("L" & stRow) = MonthName(Month(i)) & "- Salome Baazov - " & "Geo" & " Ltd "
        curMn = WorksheetFunction.EDate(i, 1)
    Else
        wO.Range("B" & stRow) = Format(i, "DD-MM-YYYY")
        wO.Range("H" & stRow) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(dbMin, dbMax) + (WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 1) * 0.5)
        wO.Range("L" & stRow) = "=" & Chr(34) & cet & Chr(34)
    End If

    stRow = stRow + 1
    i = i + intVal(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(LBound(intVal), UBound(intVal))) - 1
Next i

wO.Rows(stRow).EntireRow.Delete
wO.Range("I" & stRow).Formula = "=SUM(I19:I" & stRow - 1 & ")"
wO.Range("H" & stRow).Formula = "=SUM(H19:H" & stRow - 1 & ")"

wO.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
STG.Range("B5") = stRow - 1
MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Protip: when working with dates, use the `Date` type and the functions from the `VBA.DateTime` module.

Comment: There are a number of implicit typing issues here. `Dim a, b, c, d As Foo` declares `a`, `b`, and `c` as implicit `Variant`, and `d` as `Foo`. This leads to all kinds of implicit type conversions happening behind your back ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes I understand they are Variant type but then why would it would add  a leading space to `Day(i)` result also to i as well ? is it only because of type declaration?

Comment: There's no extra space. Numbers output to the immediate pane simply leave a spot for a negative sign. Hmm, hold on a sec.

Comment: @Mat'sMug well then we come to the same question again of this question's title

Comment: @A.S.H I already checked interestingly then both returned 2 the len(Day(i)) and len(salday(0)) even though there was leading space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are comparing two `Variant`s with different types (As it turned out after our discussions... thx @MatsMug). The comparison result is undefined behavior when comparing `Variants` of different types, one numeric and one String.

It's the [**Variant anomalies**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354228/for-v-1-to-v-and-for-each-v-in-v-different-behavior-with-different-types) once again.. Consider this MCVE:

```
Sub Test1()
  Dim i, salday
  i = CDate("5/30/2017")
  salday = Split("20-20-20", "-")

  Debug.Print Day(i), salday(0)                  '  30    20
  Debug.Print Day(i) > salday(0)                 '  False
  Debug.Print Day(i) > CStr(salday(0))           '  True
  '                    ^^^^
  Debug.Print Val(Day(i)) > salday(0)            '  True
  '           ^^^^
End Sub
```

Although salday(0) is a `String Variant`, explicitly converting it to `String` with `CStr` solved the issue. However, without that conversion, the comparison failed. **VBA did not implicitly convert the number to a string or vice-versa. It compared two Variants of different types and returned a rubbish result.**

For more about the *Variant curse*, read [For v=1 to v and For each v in v -- different behavior with different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354228/for-v-1-to-v-and-for-each-v-in-v-different-behavior-with-different-types)

As it turns out, using `CLng` or `Val` to force number comparison is the safe way to go, or `CStr` to force text comparison.

---

Consider further these three simple examples:

```
Sub Test1()
  Dim x, y: x = 30: y = "20"
  Debug.Print x > y               ' False !!
End Sub

Sub Test2()
  Dim x As Long, y: x = 30: y = "20"
  '       ^^^^^^
  Debug.Print x > y             ' True
End Sub

Sub Test3()
  Dim x, y As String:  x = 30: y = "20"
  '           ^^^^^^
  Debug.Print x > y             ' True
End Sub
```

As you can see, when both variables, the number and the string, were declared variants, the comparison is rubbish. When at least one of them is explicit, the comparison succeeds!

Comment: Ohh yes thanks I missed that I thought if isnumeric returns true then it must be a number

Comment: But why would Day(i) return a number with space ?

Comment: @newguy it happens :) but where does that leading space come from? a bug? it's weird indeed.

Comment: even ?i returns " 42766" with leading space and i is For i = CLng(stDate) To CLng(enDate) where stDate and enDate are dates

Comment: At first I thought that you had an array called `Day`, but now that I see you're using VBA's `Day` function, I found it *very very weird*.

Comment: I added full code again just in case if it helps. Maybe because I didn't declare them as Date and as variants?

Comment: I'd go with `CLng` over `Val`, but yeah that works. @newguy consider marking this answer as accepted: mine is probably useful, but misses the crux of the problem.

Comment: @Mat'sMug This is great. I am almost sure that RD is becoming a must for professional programming in VBA.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> Dim stDate, enDate
> ```

This instruction declares two `Variant` variables. They're assigned here:

> ```
> stDate = STG.Range("B2"): enDate = STG.Range("B4")
> ```

Assuming `[B2]` and `[B4]` contain actual date values, at that point the variables contain a `Variant/Date`. That's because the implicit code here is as follows:

```
stDate = STG.Range("B2").Value: enDate = STG.Range("B4").Value
```

But you probably know that already. Moving on.

> ```
> salDay = Split(STG.Range("B6"), "-")
> ```

`salDay` is also an implicit `Variant`. That instruction is quite loaded though. Here's the implicit code:

```
salDay = Split(CStr(STG.Range("B6").Value), "-")
```

This makes `salDay` an array of strings. So here we are:

> ```
> ?Day(i)
>  31 
> ?salday(0)
> 20
> ```

The leading space in front of `31` is because the immediate pane always leaves a spot for a negative sign. `salDay(0)` being a `String`, there's no leading space. That was your clue right there.

> ```
> ?Day(i)>salday(0)
> False
> ```

With `salday(0)` being a `String`, we're doing a string comparison here, [as was already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338542/1188513). Except there's no leading space in front of the 31; the implicit code is this, because the type of `Day(i)` is `Integer`:

```
?CStr(Day(i)) > salDay(0)
False
```

---

The solution is to get rid of `salDay` altogether: you don't need it. Assuming `[B6]` also contains an actual date, you can get the day into an `Integer` right away:

```
?Day(STG.Range("B6").Value)
```

As a bonus you decouple your code from the string representation of the underlying date value that's in your worksheet, so changing the `NumberFormat` won't break your code. Always treat dates as such!

Comment: The implicit string conversion, yeah.

Comment: Good explanation. So as it turns out comparing an int to a string does not convert either type to the other for the comparison?!! Weird weird VBA.

Comment: @A.S.H it does... that's why we end up with a string comparison, because *one* of the operands is a string :-)

Comment: But `?"31" > "20"` returns True?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? By any alpha sort "3" is greater than "2"!

Comment: Of course, but what are then `CStr(Day(i))` and `salDay(0)` ? why `?Day(i) > salDay(0)` returned false?

Comment: There's no checkmark anywhere I thnk.. it's yet another vexing situation with VBA's  `Variant`... Really unexpected, and the list goes on :D

Comment: Yeah! signal comparison of variants and advice explicit conversion! (y) `Val` for numeric comparison and `CStr` for string comparison.. maybe. As it turns out, at least one of the two must be explicit to be on the safe side. idk but something to investigate further here.