# Comparing values of cells in a column with ComboBox value input by user

Tags: vba, excel

I am not able to compare the values of a cells in a column with combobox value input.

I have 2 workbooks **tests**(contains ComboBox2) and **test1**(contains a column whose cells are compared with ComboBox2.value)

I have a for loop to achieve this.

```
For i = 1 To LastRow

    If wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1) = ComboBox2.Value Then
         'do something
    End If
Next i
```

I have debugged the code and I understood that `if` `statement` doesn't execute even after a match.

How can I fix it ?

**EDIT  :**

Also I would like to know how you can add two cell values because directly adding it is showing incorrect output.
For example

`wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1) + wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 3)`

Comment: Before jumping into the logic, have you checked if wkbSource works properly since you are working on different workbooks?

Comment: Yes.I have checked that it works properly.

Comment: Have your tried to reference ComboBox2.Value to its corresponding workbook?

Comment: Yes it is showing valid value input by the user.

Comment: You might be victim of the *Variant curse*. Are the values you are comparing, actually numbers? If so, how were they added to the combobox?

Comment: I don't know whether they are numbers.I guess they are stored as String in ComboBox as well as cells.

Comment: Beware, Excel will take any numeric value as a number (unless explicitly formatted or preceded by single quote `'`). You might be interested in reading [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338542/4926357). Would you try this modification to see if we are on the right track: `If wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1).Text = ComboBox2.Text Then`

Comment: Should I convert the combobox value into number ?

Comment: Try comparing texts: `If wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1).Text = ComboBox2.Text Then`. Would be even better if you `Trim` them: `If Trim(wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1).Text) = Trim(ComboBox2.Text) Then`

Comment: You might be activating the other workbook and assume that you are still working on your current workbook, which you actually not. Specify your workbook and worksheet for each object.

Comment: @Tehscript I guess, just guess, that the code is within the worksheet's code module otherwise `ComboBox2` would not be found and would raise "object not set" error. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @A.S.H 
If wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1).Text = ComboBox2.Text Then
Perfect.That worked.I just have one more doubt.
How can I add the cell values ?

Comment: @A.S.H yeah it must have been within worksheet's module.

Comment: @user3126632 I will post an answer and add that requirement to it. As I am particularly interested in revealing the anomalies due to comparison of `Variant`s.

Comment: @A.S.H *Variant curse* nice one! You should post your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due (once again) to the **[Variant Comparison Curse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354228)**. See in particular the **"UPDATE 4"** of that question.

> ```
> If wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1) = ComboBox2.Value Then
> ```

This compares two `Variant`s. But, when the cell contains a number, and is not explictly formatted as `Text`, not preceded by `'` when entered. Excel will consider it as a number and so it's `.Value` will be a number `Variant`. On the other hand, `Combobox2.Value` retuned a text `Variant`, so the comparison failed!

When comparing two **`Variant`** variables, these operations will fail:

```
  2 = "2"    ' False
  3 > "2"    ' False
```

Therefore, the solution in your particular situation is to force comparing texts, using the `.Text` properties of the control and the cell. Here's how you would - for example - sum up cells that match your query:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
  If Trim(wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1).Text) =  Trim(ComboBox2.Text) Then
     'do something
      if IsNumeric(wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1).Value2) Then _
        mySum = mySum + wkbSource.Worksheets(sheet_no).Cells(i, 1).Value2
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: ++ One might spend hours to solve this because it is easy to miss the core problem.

Comment: @Tehscript yeah, and it is recently happening frequently as I noticed.